# How do I play ringtone with respecting user's sound setting?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build a call application using webrtc and socket.io. I am using firebase messaging to wake up the user. I am trying to find a way to notify user with playing a ringtone like when you get call on whatsapp they play default incoming call ringtone. I tried solutions like -

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
r.play();
```

another is -

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), notification);
mp.start();
```

but it does not respect user's sound setting i.e sound plays even when phone is put on vibrate or dnd.

Comment: should i check and play the sound? I was looking for a straight forward way which maybe available for such purpose like maybe an api which respects user's setting.

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least google in native phone app explicitly checks phone state, you can take a look here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone/+/eclair-sholes-release/src/com/android/phone

and here is the logic, enjoy spaghetti from `ring()` method =)
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone/+/eclair-sholes-release/src/com/android/phone/Ringer.java#124